# OpenBD Plugin not found

Tags: java, coldfusion, cfml, openbd, bluedragon

I have a plugin that has been successfully installed to my project according to the `bluedragon.log`:

```
25/08/15 14:35.54: PluginManager: Auto Discovery (openbdplugin-XXXX.jar)
25/08/15 14:35.54: PlugIn.Load.Installed: com.org.openbd.plugin.PinkPlugin; Pink; Version=0.1
```

But I'm not sure how to use it in cfml.

The execute method of my plugin class looks for 2 string parameters, method and parameter.

Comment: what does the plugin do?  where did you download it. A quick google search returned nothing.

Comment: I created it, not downloaded it. Turns out I had set up the plugin java file wrong. Problem solved. Future reference for anyone wondering the same, it's called with:

    <cfscript>
     result = pink('this is a string');
    </cfscript>